# Feature request: hide migrated questions with accepted answers in the 'active' tab

Tags: feature-request

Should questions migrated *to* Webmasters that already have accepted answers appear in the ['active'](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/?tab=active) tab, as they do at present? e.g.:

- [Any reason a site has 2 links to favicon?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15759/any-reason-a-site-has-2-links-to-favicon)
- [Add copyright notice to a website](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15753/add-copyright-notice-to-a-website)

It would be great to be able to filter out migrated questions with accepted solutions to see only those without accepted solutions. At present, the 'active' questions page here gets flooded with already-answered questions each time someone at SO has a clear up.

Comment: Closing as off-topic: this meta site is for things that relate to Pro Webmasters, not the entire network. This table feature request is not something that's specific to this site: it would affect other sites as well, and they should be able to comment on it.

Answer (score 1):

This question might be better asked at meta.stackoverflow.com as it's a feature of the underlying engine. I would guess the logic is that recently answered questions might be worth looking at so that question and answer can get some more up votes before they disappear off the "front page".

With the highlighting around the `n answers` box I find it easy to skip past them.

The underlying engine in the shape of the Community user also pokes old questions randomly to make them active.